# Tree of interfaces with generic argument type

Tags: typescript, generics, interface, tree

I'm struggling with some type definition for a tree of interfaces with a generic type argument. Basically, let's say I have the following interface:

```
interface Foo<S> {
   state: S
   fn: (state: S) => void
}

interface FooTree {
  [key: string]: Foo<any>
}

const tree: FooTree = { bar: { state: { something: 3, fn: (state) => {} } } }
```

What I'd like is for the state argument of the fn method to be typed based on the actual state object value. Is that even possible ? Currently, I only get unknown / any

Answer (score 0):

Does this meet your requirements:

```js
interface Foo<S> {
    state: S
    fn: (state: S) => void
}

interface FooTree {
    [key: string]: Foo<{ age: number }>
}

const tree: FooTree = { bar: { state: { age: 42 }, fn: (state) => { } } }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0B4DKA%20ZAbwChkzkBnMOSALmR1PJhHoAoqaJ6cBKZALwEAbumAATYgF9ixUJFiIUGdABUoEFCXLIA2gGsIAT3pUooAOYBdeiqyFkcC92QgArgFsARtGRS80rII6CBUyGAaLirqmoJEyF5wUPQOnHTxTi4ALABMfgA0yCzsaRD8QvFSfn5AA)

Comment: Unfortunately no as the state property may contain anything; it can't be known in advance.

Comment: If you change 42 to "42" it will throw TS compiler error, also `state` argument is narrowed, Could you please provide an example?

Comment: That's what I'm saying, the state property should not throw an error as it should be able to contain anything; basically, I would like to have typescript get the type of the `state` property to use it as argument in the `fn` method of the same object.

const truc = { 
    someKey: { 
        state: { something: 'bonjour', fn: (state: { something: string }) => {} } 
    }
}

Comment: I thought doing something like:

`interface FooTree {
    [key: string]: any extends Foo<infer S> ? Foo<S> : any
}`

would work but I guess I still don't fully understand the `infer` keyword usage.

Comment: Maybe: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0B4DKA+ZAbwChkzkBnMOSALmR1PJhHoAoqaJ6cBKZALwEAbumAATYgF9ixUJFiIUGdABUoECFlQES5ZAG0A1hACe9KlFABzALr0V2vNNkJ0IKsjBQArggeY6ppYhJToALYQYAAWNhbeNshSBAJEYZEA0mb0oZx0aRQRUbEg1vQA5ABG7gBW6D5Q5UkANMgs7HkQ-EJpUklJskA

Comment: You should  declare upfront generic for Foo

Comment: That isn't an option as I cannot know the value of `state` in advance.

Comment: @YasserLahbibi please check this article https://catchts.com/callbacks#cb_structure

Comment: hey, thanks for your help but that's the pattern I'd like to avoid (having to create a helper method), maybe I should have mentioned it before aha